# Virtualbox is not starting for server 2019, how to fix that?

Tags: virtualbox

I launched a VM which used to work earlier on a different machine by copying it from that machine.

It is just a clean server 2019 machine, no other applications installed on it.

When, I launch, I got this error.

[virtualbox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDtSb.png)

Logs are available [here](https://github.com/uday1kiran/logs/tree/master/virtualbox). Please suggest how to fix this error.

Log files:
[1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uday1kiran/logs/master/virtualbox/VBox.log)
[2](https://github.com/uday1kiran/logs/blob/master/virtualbox/VBoxHardening.log)
[3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uday1kiran/logs/master/virtualbox/VBox.log.2)

VBox.log:

Comment: Your pictures are inaccessible.

Comment: I kept the repo link as public, can you check that, I kept image there also

Comment: Yeah, I would have to download the archive file, just to see the image

Comment: No need to download, you can just click the link above, it will show the image. As you are  not able to find the "virtualbox error" link above, may be because it is in blue color. You can click use this link to open the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDtSb.png

Comment: I was talking about VBox.png

Comment: Everything is posted there on the above link quotes as "here" in blue color. You don't need to download the archive, in the web UI of github you can access individual files.If you need anything I can save there directly. The link again: https://github.com/uday1kiran/logs/tree/master/virtualbox

Comment: VBox.png https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uday1kiran/logs/master/virtualbox/VBox.png